# How to compare dates in a View?

Tags: 8, views, datetime

I'm trying to build a new View in Drupal 8. I want to display list of News. Each item has **field_date** where is date (without time) stored. And second field is **body** with basic text information.

I'm trying to set FILTER CRITERIA to display only items with date <= NOW(). It seems that it's impossible to enter this filter. There is no condition for it. Do you have idea how to enter this? This is filter what I see in modal window for new filter citerium

[image: Screenshot from View]

```
<select id="edit-options-operator" name="options[operator]" class="form-select">    
  <option value="=" selected="selected">Je rovno</option>
  <option value="!=">Není rovno</option>
  <option value="contains">Obsahuje</option>
  <option value="word">Obsahuje jakékoliv slovo</option>
  <option value="allwords">Obsahuje všechna slova</option>
  <option value="starts">Začíná na</option>
  <option value="not_starts">Does not start with</option>
  <option value="ends">Končí na</option>
  <option value="not_ends">Does not end with</option>
  <option value="not">Neobsahuje</option>
  <option value="shorterthan">Délka je kratší než</option>
  <option value="longerthan">Délka je delší než</option>
  <option value="regular_expression">Regulární výraz</option>
  <option value="empty">Je prázdný (NULL)</option>
  <option value="not empty">Není prázdný (NOT NULL)</option>
</select>
```

(Sorry for Czech localization but you can still see key of each option :)

I thought that shorterthan we be right option, but it seems to be suitable only for string. I know that Drupal 8 is still in beta today but this problem must have some solution. I'm using already included core extension Datetime.

Comment: Views integration for date fields is not complete yet, being worked on in https://www.drupal.org/node/1838242, follow that issue :)

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8.2.5 the option is available. See this picture:

[image]

Comment: Is it true that D8 is still in ***beta*** (as in the question)? I honestly doubt ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I come from see that the question have 2 years, LOL